# centering image for phones and tablets

Tags: html, css

I am creating a splash screen for an application that is built in html5 and css3, and I cannot get the image to be exactly in the middle. I need it to be in the middle for phones and tablets. Thanks for any advice or help.

Image size is 300px by 300px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know the size of the image, you can use negative margins:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -150px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Images/block elements can be centred using margins:

```
img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  }
```

Otherwise you could use the old-school `<center>` tag technique. It's still in HTML5. ;)